# convert expression $\frac{x^n}{2^{n^2}}$ to get rid of squared term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

In an expression if we have $x^n$ divided by $2^{n^2}$ i.e $2$ raised to $n$ squared how can we get rid of the square term for 2?

Essentially want to get rid of the asymmetry and express the whole thing in n terms or $n^2$ terms for both x and 2.

Comment: If you would like to increase the number of people who will read your post, you should typeset the mathematics in [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but you probably cannot get rid of the asymmetry the way you seem to want. E.g. you can do something like $\left ({\frac{x^{1/n}}{2}}\right)^{n^2}$, but that's hardly any more "symmetric" than the original. Ditto for @gimusi's answer.